# Why does field splitting of WORD not occur in `case WORD in` statement when WORD is a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, dash-shell

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
a="foo  bar"

case $a in
    "foo  bar")
        echo case 1
        ;;
esac

case foo  bar in
    "foo  bar")
        echo case 2
        ;;
esac
```

Executing this with `bash` leads to the following output and error.

```
case 1
foo: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `bar'
foo: line 10: `case foo  bar in'
```

Executing this with `dash`:

```
case 1
foo: 10: foo: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")` leads to the following output and error.
```

I don't understand why the first `case` statement succeeds but the second one does not.

As per the POSIX document at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05, field splitting would occur in either case, so after `$a` is expanded to `foo  bar` in the first `case` statement, it should be equivalent to the second one.

So both should fail. Why does the first `case` statement succeed?

Comment: Because the first is a single string and the second isn't ?

Comment: @123 First `touch "foo bar"`. Then by your logic, `a="foo bar"; ls $a` should list the file `foo bar` but `ls foo bar` should fail to do so "because the first is a single string and the second isn't". But in reality, both commands fail because [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) occurs in both cases and in both cases we have two words, not one, after field splitting.

Comment: Why are you arguing about something you clearly don't understand? Look at the answer below.

Comment: @123 I am arguing about something *I am trying to understand*. If I clearly understood this subject, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. I have read the answer below. It is good. I have upvoted and accepted it as the correct answer. That doesn't change the fact that I don't understand your comment above and how it explains the observed behaviour in the question, i.e. why the first is a single string in `case $a` when it is not so in `ls $a`.

Comment: So you read the answer but don't understand my comment ?  `I am trying to understand` You never asked for any clarification of anything. You just started explaining field splitting.

Comment: @123 I read the answer. It explains that there is no field splitting in case of `case`. Your comment stated that in the first case, it is a single string. Why? I didn't understand that. That's why I commented what I commented. 5 minutes later, the answer by @l3x below explained that field splitting does not occur in `case` and I accepted it as the correct answer. I didn't ask for any clarification in the comment because I have already asked it in  my question. I just posted what looked like a contradiction to your comment in order to keep the comment short and set the discussion rolling.

Comment: I don't understand what resolution you want from this?

Comment: @123 None. The question has been already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word splitting is *not* done in the first case for the *word* used in *case* statement. From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):

**Case Conditional Construct**

> The conditional construct case shall execute the compound-list
>   corresponding to the first one of several patterns (see Pattern
>   Matching Notation) that is matched by the string resulting from the
>   tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, and quote removal of the given word.

So whether you quote the *word* or not, it's not going to be expanded and is safe without quotes.

```
case $a in  
   ...
esac
```

and

```
case "$a" in    
   ...
esac
```

are going to work as expected.

Clearly, this is not equivalent to the second example where you have *two* words in the case statement.